# Выбрать диапазон чисел из предложения

Tags: php

Есть запись

> 2019: 100 001 - 200 000 € without VAT

как из нее выбрать только эту часть?

> 100 001 - 200 000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно изучить регулярные выражения. Они дают много возможностей. Наверняка Ваша задача имеет свои нюнасы. Но конкретно с этой строкой я бы сделал так:

1) Очистил бы от пробелов (И цифры на выходе нормальные будут, регулярное выражение проще)

2) Выбрал бы через регулярное выражение цифры между которыми есть дефис. При желании их можно даже в разные переменные отправить. Скобками выделяем в регулярном выражении части, которые хотели бы сохранить в $result.

```
$str = "2019: 100 001 - 200 000 € without VAT";
$str = str_replace(" ", "", $str);
preg_match("/([0-9]*-[0-9]*)/", $str, $result);
$result = $result[0];
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!! :)